# How to get value of chosen bit position from byte word

Tags: python

I try get value of bit from variable `a=bin(ord("f"))`. Does exist method, like `a.get(5)` or somethikg else to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ord("f") >> (bit_number - 1) & 1` will work

**Example** (will print all bits in `ord('f')`):

```
class bitwise(int):

    def get(self, num):
        return self >> (num - 1) & 1

    def len(self):
        return len(bin(self)[2:])


a = bitwise(ord('f'))

print(a, bin(a))

for x in range(1, a.len()+1):
    print(a.get(x))
```

Printing

```
102 0b1100110
0
1
1
0
0
1
1
```

**Explanation:**

This solution is based entirely on [bitwise operations](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators).

`a >> b` shifts all bits in `a` to the right by `b` positions and `(a >> b) & 1` gets the last bit in the result (the target one in our case).

Comment: can you explain `>> x & 1`